# Expectation conditioned on sum and difference of two random variables

Tags: probability, probability-theory, measure-theory, expected-value, conditional-expectation

Suppose $X, Y$ are independent, identically distributed, integrable random variables. Let $h:\mathbb{R}^2 \to \mathbb{R}$ be a bounded Borel-measurable function.

What is $\mathbb{E}[h(X, Y)\space |\space X+Y, X-Y]$? I can't really see how this conditioning would work...

Comment: Given $X+Y$, $X-Y$, you can accurately determine $X, Y$. Hence you can accurately determine the value of $h(X, Y)$ which will be its expectation

Comment: @whoisit So would the answer just be $h(\frac{(X+Y)+(X-Y)}{2}, \frac{(X+Y)-(X-Y)}{2})$ almost surely?

Comment: Not sure of the need for "almost surely": the expectation is a constant RV: $h\left(\frac{(X+Y)+(X-Y)}{2}, \frac{(X+Y)-(X-Y)}{2}\right)$; Also we haven't used the IIDness or integrability of $X$ and $Y$

Comment: the answer is $h(X, Y)$

Comment: @whoisit I guess conditional expectations are only defined almost surely, so it still makes sense to include it.

Comment: @Mason  Well, indeed $X=\dfrac{(X+Y)-(X+Y)}{2}$ and $Y=\dfrac{(X+Y)-(X-Y)}{2}$, but it is best practice to give the answer in terms of the variables *as they appear* in the conditioning clause.  As awkward as that may look.